# Observer for 'catalog_product_prepare_save' can't work

Tags: event-observer

code below.
config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Bkt_Printimages>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Bkt_Printimages>
    </modules>

    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_prepare_save>
                <observers>
                    <bkt_printimages_model_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Bkt_Printimages_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>AddCoustomOptionToProduct</method>
                    </bkt_printimages_model_observer>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_prepare_save>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Observer.php

```
<?php

class Bkt_Printimages_Model_Observer{

    public function AddCoustomOptionToProduct($observer){

        Mage::log('[bktlog] product save log');
    }
}
?>
```

but no log in "var/log/system.log", why? How to do that? 
Some body help me, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you're missing at least this bit, to tell magento where your model classes are

```
<global>
    <models>
        <Bkt_Printimages>
            <class>Bkt_Printimages_Model</class>
        </Bkt_Printimages>
    </models>
</global>
```

Comment: It still not work. I'm not sure if my operation is correct, after install this code, my step is: compile magento -> clear cache -> add a simple product, and no log show.

Comment: have you created app/etc/Bkt_Printimages.xml and enabled the module?

Comment: Yes, I have, but app/etc/modules/Bkt_Printimages.xml, and this module can find in configuration of admin panel.

Comment: I have found the failed reason. I named my module directory 'PrintImages', it's incorrect, should be 'Printimages'. Thank you vary much, @Richard!